# No more connection after trying to set static ip address

Tags: internet

I was trying to set a static IP adress for domoticz using `sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf` and changed some things. Now I no longer have wifi nor lan connection on my rpi 4.

I only started my pi up for the 2nd time so keep in mind that I know barely anything of it.

What commands should I do as I have no idea how to fix this

When I hover over the internet icon it says: connection to dhcpcd lost
When I click on the internet icon it says: no wireless interfaces found

UPDATE:
I removed the unnessesary parts in /etc/network/interfaces, rebooted and it's all back. I think it had to do with a wrong IP address

Comment: "Change some things" is not very precise. The solution is to change those things back. If you don't remember what you changed, copy and paste the content of the file you changed, `dhcpd.conf` into your question above and format it as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. Click the **Answer Your Own Question** button and write the solution in the answer. Then after the required wait period accept your answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✓ and turn it green ✅. This will mark the problem solved and help others.

Comment: @user68186: In most cases, I'd agree. In this case, the question and answer are too vague to be of any use. I feel it should be deleted.

Comment: @Seamus The comment above is what I write to all new contributors who are not familiar with the stack exchange sites and how they work and write "SOLVED" in the question title and put the answer inside the question. In this particular case, I agree with you on the quality of the question and answer and I have flagged the question for deletion as well. I don't have enough reputation for vote to close yet.

Answer (score -1):

I removed the unnessesary parts in /etc/network/interfaces, rebooted and it's all back. I think it had to do with a wrong IP address

Comment: what is `unnessesary parts`?